# How to INSERT OR UPDATE while MATCHING a non Primary Key without updating existing Primary Key?

Tags: firebird

I'm currently working with Firebird and attempting to utilize [UPDATE OR INSERT](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-update-or-insert.html) functionality in order to solve a particular new case within our software. Basically, we are needing to pull data off of a source and put it into an existing table and then update that data at regular intervals and adding any new references. The source is not a database so it isn't a matter of using MERGE to link the two tables (unless we make a separate table and then merge it, but that seems unnecessary).

The problem rests on the fact we cannot use the primary key of the existing table for matching, because we need to match based off of the ID we get from the source. We can use the MATCHING clause no problem but the issue becomes that the primary key of the existing table will be updated to the next key every time because it has to be in the query because of the insertion chance. Here is the query (along with c# parameter additions) to demonstrate the problem.

```
UPDATE OR INSERT INTO existingtable (PrimaryKey, UniqueSourceID, Data) VALUES (?,?,?) MATCHING (UniqueSourceID);

this.AddInParameter("PrimaryKey", FbDbType.Integer, itemID);

this.AddInParameter("UniqueSourceID", FbDbType.Integer, source.id);

this.AddInParameter("Data", FbDbType.SmallInt, source.data);
```

Problem is shown that every time the UPDATE triggers, the primary key will also change to the next incremented key I need a way to leave the primary key alone when updating, but if it is inserting I need to insert it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not generate primary key manually, let a trigger generate it when nessesary:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_existingtable;

SET TERM ^ ;

CREATE TRIGGER Gen_PK FOR existingtable
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  IF(NEW.PrimaryKey IS NULL)THEN NEW.PrimaryKey = NEXT VALUE FOR seq_existingtable;
END^

SET TERM ; ^
```

Now you can omit the PK field from your statement:

```sql
UPDATE OR INSERT INTO existingtable (UniqueSourceID, Data) VALUES (?,?) MATCHING (UniqueSourceID);
```

and when the `insert` is triggered by the statement then the trigger will take care of creating the PK. If you need to know the generated PK then use the `RETURNING` clause of the `UPDATE OR INSERT` statement.

Comment: I'm getting a Dynamic SQL Error on the 'unknown token CREATE' (the one on create Trigger when I run that. I also have an existing 'generator' called 'ITEMX' with a value of 857 that we use for our primary key in this table. I'm assuming I can use this value to make the trigger continue on with? Previously we were using `SELECT GEN_ID(ITEMX,1) FROM RDB$DATABASE` and getting that value, then manually passing it into the primary key value of the query.

Comment: If you already have a generator (aka sequence) for that table then of course continue to use it, ie do not create new one, just use it's name in the trigger. What tool do you use to create the trigger? You might need to set the statement terminator, see updated code in the answer.

Comment: Thanks so much, figured out what I mistyped (I didn't need the terminator after all) and it is working with my existing generator.